# Wrapping Vue computed properties and methods while preserving type signature on Vue.extend constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I want to wrap all my defined methods and computed properties in a function that times their execution.

I want to preserve the IntelliSense predictions derived from the type signature of `Vue.extend({...`

I've failed to create my own method while maintaining the complex type signature without having to copy dozens of files from the `vue.d.ts` typings.

I've gotten moderate success from replacing `Vue.extend` before calling it, but I'd rather just have my own constructor method with the same typing benefits of the Vue one.

Bulky but working example, which requires `"noImplicitThis": false` in .tsconfig:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ computedValue }}
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';

    const ext = Vue.extend;
    Vue.extend = function (x: any, ...rest:any[]) {
        const f = x.computed.computedValue;
        console.log(x, rest);
        x.computed.computedValue = function () {
            const start = Date.now();
            const rtn = f.call(this, x, ...rest);
            console.log(`Took ${(Date.now() - start) / 1000} seconds`);
            return rtn;
        }
        return ext.call(this, x, ...rest);
    } as any

    const component = Vue.extend({
        computed: {
            computedValue() {
                return 'passed';
            }
        }
    });
    Vue.extend = ext;
    export default component;
</script>
```

Desired result: a method that is called instead of `Vue.extend` that will wrap the computed properties and methods in a chronometer while preserving IntelliSense on the component

Result so far: A bulky implementation that requires a lot of intervention in the implementation of each component in order to be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While typing up the example component for this, I managed to achieve what I wanted: A single method that wraps `Vue.extend` while hooking in a chronometer on certain component methods.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps } from 'vue/types/options';
import { ExtendedVue } from 'vue/types/vue';

export function wrap<Data, Methods, Computed, PropNames extends string = never>
    (options: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<Vue, Data, Methods, Computed, PropNames>):
    ExtendedVue<Vue, Data, Methods, Computed, Record<PropNames, any>> {
    if ('computed' in options) {
        Object.keys(options.computed as any).forEach((key: string) => {
            const f: Function = (options.computed as any)[key] as any as Function;
            (options.computed as any)[key] = function (...args: any[]) {
                const start = Date.now();
                const rtn = f.apply(this, args);
                console.log(`${key} took ${(Date.now() - start) / 1000} seconds.`);
                return rtn;
            };
        });
    }
    if ('methods' in options) {
        Object.keys(options.methods as any).forEach((key: string) => {
            const f: Function = (options.methods as any)[key] as any as Function;
            (options.methods as any)[key] = function (...args: any[]) {
                const start = Date.now();
                const rtn = f.apply(this, args);
                console.log(`${key} took ${(Date.now() - start) / 1000} seconds.`);
                return rtn;
            };
        });
    }
    return Vue.extend(options);
}
```

Simple call `wrap({...componentOptions})` rather than `Vue.extend({...componentOptions})` and it will hook the chronometer.

`$options` doesn't play too nice, but being a little sneaky seems to suppress errors

```
    export default wrap({
        ...{
            a: 4
        },
    });
```